# read txt file in google colab

Tags: python, txt

enter image description here
I have a database in txt format and I just want to read numbers in float format. By what order is this possible?
From line 9 to 254126
And columns 0 to 31
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV6mu.png

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV6mu.png)

Comment: can you show an example of your txt file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each float is on a new line

```
with open(filename) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    allNums = [float(line.rstrip()) for line in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.read_csv('/content/dummy.txt', usecols=list(range(0,32)),nrows=254126, skiprows=8)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).